# How to find a particular position on every screen?

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net, css

**I want to find coordinates of a particular windows screen portion.** I have to pass these as parameter to some JavaScript function. This function will display a tool-tip div on a particular position of page ( 2 inch above bottom right corner) no matter what resolution or screen size or browser a visitor may have.

For demonstration please see this link http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/submitted-scripts/title-to-note/title-to-note.html

Comment: What if the screen's only 2 inches tall? :-)

Comment: Pixels can be done but how do you tell if you 800x600 display is on a 15inch monitor or a blind guy using a 25"

Comment: @Pointy plz see this http://www.dhtmlgoodies.com/submitted-scripts/title-to-note/title-to-note.html

Comment: @Chad plz see the link I pasted in my edited question. thanks

Comment: That puts it at a pixel position not a inches measurement.  2 inches on a display 1680x1050 22" is a different pixel number than a 11" net book running at 960x540.  You can do it a percentage but you are not going to get exactly 2 inches on all displays.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
<div style="position:absolute; bottom: 2in; right: 0px;">test</div>
```

EDIT:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    var height = $(window).height();
    var width = $(window).width();
    alert('width: '+width+'; heigth: '+height);
});
```

now to position your div, you'll just need to absolute position your div

top:height - div height - 2 inches.

left: width - div width

Comment: Thompson, can I find it with javascript ? I want to calculte and pass to a function.

Answer (score 2):

```
.tooltip {position: absolute; bottom: 40px; right: 40px;}
.page-wrapper {position: relative;}
<div class="page-wrapper">
//website content
</div>
<div class="tooltip">
//tooltip content
</div>
```